# Discord.py warning when you're being robbed

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having trouble with this line of code... It doesn't seem to work. It's supposed to warn you when you are being robbed. It doesn't work. Please help!

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('pls rob <@709809471571886112>'):
    await message.channel.send("<@709809471571886112> You're being robbed!")

  if message.content.startswith('pls rob <@717501219639132225>'):
    await message.channel.send("<@717501219639132225> You're being robbed!")
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"Doesn't work" is not a problem specificaiton.

Comment: Heres the thing... I don't get any errors from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing this in GGberry's response, you can use a regex with `?` to mark the `!` character as optional.

```
import re

if re.match(r'pls rob <!?@709809471571886112>', message.content) is not None:
    # send message
```

You can also collect the user ids in a tuple and check for them in a loop, rather than duplicating the logic

```
import re
USER_IDS = (709809471571886112, 717501219639132225)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for user_id in USER_IDS:
        if re.match(rf'pls rob <!?@{user_id}>', message.content) is not None:
            await message.channel.send(f"<@{user_id}> You're being robbed!")
```

Answer (score 4):

I see that you're trying to be notified yourself when someone does `pls rob <@709809471571886112>`. Checking if a message starts with "pls rob <@709809471571886112>" isn't reliable, because a user mention could be `<@!ID>` or `<@ID>`.

A more reliable way to define your function would be to check `pls rob` and your ID seperatly:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if 'pls rob' in message.content and '709809471571886112' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send("<@709809471571886112> You're being robbed!")

  if 'pls rob' in message.content and '717501219639132225' in message.content:
    await message.channel.send("<@717501219639132225> You're being robbed!")
```

So basically, you don't need to include the `<@>` between the IDs.